# Fastest way to calculate correlation in every row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, I have a table `data` of millions of rows. I want to carry out correlation study for every row (from the 1st to the current row minus 1). For e.g. the 1st rows is omitted. The 2nd row's `result` column is to be supplied with the correlation using the 1st row. The 3rd row's `result` column is to be supplied with the correlation using the 1st and 2nd row. And so on.

Correlation for the entire table can be calculated using:

```
SELECT (Count(*)*Sum(x*y)-Sum(x)*Sum(y))/
         (sqrt(Count(*)*Sum(x*x)-Sum(x)*Sum(x))*
          sqrt(Count(*)*Sum(y*y)-Sum(y)*Sum(y))) AS TotalCorelation FROM Data;
```

I want to avoid using Joins as much as possible as it takes lots of time, sometimes even timeout error, above 300 seconds). What's the other alternative?

Example table Data Structure:

```
id, x, y, result
1 , 4, 2, null
2 , 6, 3, -0.2312
3 , 5, 5, 0.42312
4 , 6, 2, -0.5231
5 , 5, 5, 0.22312
6 , 3, 7, -0.2312
7 , 2, 9, 0.42231
8 , 7, 2, 0.32253
9 , 9, 5, 0.32431

id : primary key 
x and y : The data 
result: correlation
```

Comment: Is there a formula to calculate the correlation of rows 1..N based on the correlation of 1..N-1 and the data in row N? If not, this is an N^2 algorithm.

Comment: well, yes, the sql query that i have pasted above calculates correlation between X and Y for 1..N rows

Comment: I know that. The question is: if you know the correlation for 1..N rows (call that C), can you calculate the correlation of rows 1..N+1 using only C and row N+1 -- not going through all previous N rows.

Comment: oh! i have no idea! :|
sorry :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is it:

```
SELECT d2.ID, d2.x, d2.y, d2.result, 
       (Count(*)*Sum(d1.x*d1.y)-Sum(d1.x)*Sum(d1.y))/
         (sqrt(Count(*)*Sum(d1.x*d1.x)-Sum(d1.x)*Sum(d1.x))*
          sqrt(Count(*)*Sum(d1.y*d1.y)-Sum(d1.y)*Sum(d1.y))) AS TotalCorelation
FROM Data d1
RIGHT JOIN Data d2 ON d1.id < d2.id
GROUP BY d2.ID
ORDER BY d2.ID
```

Without a closed form for calculating correlation of N+1 from N rows, you have to use a quadratic join like this.

I'm assuming that your basic formula is correct. But I'm not sure it is -- when I just run it on the total dataset, I don't get the result `0.32431`, I get `-0.552773693079`.

Here's a linear implementation:

```
SET @SumX = 0;
SET @SumY = 0;
SET @Count = 0;
SET @SumX2 = 0;
SET @SumY2 = 0;
SET @SumXY = 0;

SELECT id, x, y,
       @SumX := @SumX + x AS SumX,
       @SumY := @SumY + y AS SumY,
       @Count := @Count + 1 AS ct,
       @SumX2 := @SumX2 + x*x AS SumX2,
       @SumY2 := @SumY2 + y*y AS SumY2,
       @SumXY := @SumXY + x*y AS SumXY,
       IF(@Count > 1,
          (@Count*@SumXY-@SumX*@SumY)/
            (sqrt(@Count*@SumX2-@SumX*@SumX)*
             sqrt(@Count*@SumY2-@SumY*@SumY)), NULL) AS TotalCorelation
FROM DATA
ORDER BY id
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d5369/9)

Comment: here is the result: Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 45.8917 sec) [ID: 10 - 10]

Comment: i did the test only on 3800 rows and took 45 seconds! so, if the rows is in millions then i'll take ages :(

Comment: Like I said, it's a quadratic problem.

Comment: Actually, there may be a way to optimize it. All those SUMs can be calculated incrementally in a subquery.

Comment: but many a time i get several other probs related to time consumption because of joins... So just wanna find out a solution to avoid joins and use arrays instead (which is unfortunately not supported in mysql)

Comment: ah, if i do the SUMs in subquery. i'll need to make another temporary column?

Comment: i've marked it done cos i don't think my question is upto the mark. i'll create a new question a bit similar to this! :|

Comment: Question seemed fine to me.

Comment: hmmmm.... i'll ask another question and see what happens to that question :) Anyways, thanks a million for such lightning speed answers :) so kind of u :)

Comment: I've got a solution that's linear and doesn't require a subquery or join, so get going with that new question.

Comment: Your formula is right (it gets the same result as calculator website), your sample results are wrong.

Comment: oh, yes, sample results are just example! i forgot to mention that! sorry!

Comment: I added my linear solution here, it doesn't seem to fit the new question, although maybe the techniques used do.

Comment: hmmm.... now i feel that mysql lacks some common statistical function, array variable, and the inability to retrieve a particular rows different from the current row (without using joins)  *i might be wrong cos m no mysql expert*

Comment: wow! ur code runs really fast!!!! :) *Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 3,499 total, Query took 0.0382 sec) [id: 9 - 32761]*

Comment: Relational databases generally don't have arrays, you're supposed to use relations for that. But it does have statistical functions like AVG, STDDEV, and VARIANCE. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: using Power(Sum(d1.x), 2) instead of  Sum(d1.x)*Sum(d1.x) gains more speed. (And it's spelled correlation)